# Can I use a dative gerund for: thank you for helping me?

Tags: dative, gerund

Actually I came across multiple situations in my thoughts where i came across the words 'for + verb' amd always wonder how to translate them.

'thanks for helping me'? Is an example though. Can i use a gerund dative for this like so?:

Gratias tibi ago mihi iuvando

Comment: Normally, We'd translate such sentences with the conjunction 'quod' "gratias tibi ago quod me adiuves"

Comment: @Kai: Literally: "I give thanks to you for the helping to/ for me." Do you think it works?

Comment: @ManuelCauãRebouças If you cite some sources on that, you could make that an answer.

Comment: @cmw There's a quote like this in Cicero. I think it's "liberas" I once saw it in the grammar I use.